# CSV reader picks up garbage in the first few characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to read the first line of a CSV file and assign it to `header`. The CSV file looks like this:

```
TIME,DAY,MONTH,YEAR
"3:21","23","FEB","2018"
"3:23","23","FEB","2018"
...
```

Here is the code:

```
import csv

with open("20180223.csv") as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    header = next(rdr)
    print(header)
```

I expect the output to look like:

```
['TIME', 'DAY', 'MONTH', 'YEAR']
```

However the output looks like this:

```
['ï»¿TIME', 'DAY', 'MONTH', 'YEAR']
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That first character is the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character.

Try this:

```
with open("20180223.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvfile:
```

This advice is somewhat hidden away in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html), but it is there:

> In some areas, it is also convention to use a “BOM” at the start of
>   UTF-8 encoded files; the name is misleading since UTF-8 is not
>   byte-order dependent. The mark simply announces that the file is
>   encoded in UTF-8. Use the ‘utf-8-sig’ codec to automatically skip the
>   mark if present for reading such files.

Comment: "sig" in "utf-8-sig" is the abbreviation of "signature" (i.e. signature utf-8 file). Using utf-8-sig to read a file will treat BOM as file info. instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do this to get rid of this Byte Order Mark, since you know for sure it exists:

```
$ss = substr(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.csv'), 3);
```